# How can I display a Wysiwyg editor field on my post page using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I created a Custom Wysiwyg field and I would like to display it on a custom post template that I created.

[image]

I would like my custom field (fashion_header) to appear on my custom Post template
[image]

After creating my field (using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin) and publishing my changes, I inserted the following code into my Post Template (single-fashion.php).

```
<p><?php the_field('fashion_header'); ?></p>
```

But for some reason my field isn't showing up.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a rule for your custom field in order to make it appear on your custom post type. Somehow like this:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I'm surprised I over looked this